# Testing for CCS Injection

Tags: tls, openssl, injection

I'm trying to test for a CCS Injection. I have found two prevailant methods to do so

1. Use nmap's [ssl-ccs-injection nse script](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-ccs-injection.html)
2. Tripwire's [OpenSSL-CCS-Inject-Test](https://github.com/Tripwire/OpenSSL-CCS-Inject-Test)

Both are pretty simple to use, however, they are giving me different results. nmap's script gives me a STATUS: Vulnerable while Tripwire's script gives me a "No need to patch" message. What do I believe/what do I do?

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @korockinout13 - Is there an article that can help me to do so?

Comment: Run the attack while capturing in wireshark. Attempt to decrypt the traffic using a key, which you can lookup how to use.

Comment: Possibly a false-positive in Nmap's script. Please give any info you can at https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/1322 so we can resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

> In order to exploit the vulnerablity, a MITM attacker would
>   effectively do the following:
>
> o Wait for a new TLS connection, followed by the ClientHello
>   ServerHello handshake messages.
>
> o Issue a CCS packet in both the directions, which causes the OpenSSL
>   code to use a zero length pre master secret key. The packet is sent to
>   both ends of the connection. Session Keys are derived using a zero
>   length pre master secret key, and future session keys also share this
>   weakness.
>
> o Renegotiate the handshake parameters.
>
> o The attacker is now able to decrypt or even modify the packets in
>   transit.
>
> The script works by sending a 'ChangeCipherSpec' message out of order
>   and checking whether the server returns an 'UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE' alert
>   record or not. Since a non-patched server would simply accept this
>   message, the CCS packet is sent twice, in order to force an alert from
>   the server. If the alert type is different than 'UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE',
>   we can conclude the server is vulnerable.

Source: https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-ccs-injection.html

You can use openssl s_client in linux for sending packets to the server and confirming the vulnerability manually.

Moreover I will suggest you to use testssl.sh available on https://testssl.sh because the tool is way more comprehensive and accurate.

Comment: if you are going to copy/paste and answer from somewhere, at least link to the source ...

Comment: Since the quoted part comes from a link that's in the question itself, your answer is using `s_client` to test manually, but you do not explain how to do that. Can you expand that part?